# In Android EditText, how to force writing uppercase?

Tags: android, android-edittext, uppercase

In my Android application I have different `EditText` where the user can enter information. But I need to force user to write in uppercase letters.
Do you know a function to do that?

Answer (score 392):

Android actually has a [built-in InputFilter just for this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.AllCaps.html)!

```
edittext.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.AllCaps()});
```

Be careful, `setFilters` **will reset all other attributes** which were set via XML (i.e. `maxLines`, `inputType`,`imeOptinos`...). To prevent this, add you Filter(s) to the already existing ones.

```
InputFilter[] editFilters = <EditText>.getFilters();
InputFilter[] newFilters = new InputFilter[editFilters.length + 1];
System.arraycopy(editFilters, 0, newFilters, 0, editFilters.length);
newFilters[editFilters.length] = <YOUR_FILTER>;  
<EditText>.setFilters(newFilters);
```

Comment: this is the best answer : the lower case letters are converted automatically. Simple and efficient. Thanks

Comment: Yes! This is the best answer! The code should be `edittext.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.AllCaps()});` though.

Comment: this should be the answer and @Arthur is right it should be `edittext.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.AllCaps()});`

Comment: OK you folks were right, I updated my answer.  Thanks for helping improve this!!

Comment: Anyway to do this in xml?

Comment: this is the simplest answer i've found.

Comment: Instead of uppercasing the text using TextWatcher I found this as better answer. My life now is a lie. +1 For this

Comment: To avoid overriding the filters you set on xml (for eg. `maxLength`), try to append the `InputFilter.AllCaps()` to `editText.getFilters` array. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18934659/3890983

Comment: @Johan see http://android--code.blogspot.com/2015/08/android-edittext-all-caps.html. This could be included in the answer too in fact.

Comment: And set EditText xml property to: `android:inputType="text|textCapCharacters"`

Comment: It works @ErickBergmann. But after finding the solution I think, why not just parsing data to Capital in the save button

Comment: Or in Kotlin just `editText.filters = editText.filters + InputFilter.AllCaps()`

Comment: Better yet: `editText.filters += InputFilter.AllCaps()`
Kotlin's wonderful! <3

Comment: Or you can even create an extension function called `addFilter` on `EditText` that that does this if you want to be more verbose why it's done this way.

Answer (score 139):

If you want <s>to force user to write in</s> uppercase letters *by default* in your EditText, you just need to add `android:inputType="textCapCharacters"`. (User can still manually change to lowercase.)

Comment: nothing prevents the User press 'shift' and write a letter lowercased.

Comment: Agree with Fernando, while it does default the keyboard to caps, it does not require them.

Comment: User can use shift button to enter small case letter as said by @Fernando

Comment: this is a good solution to let force user to start with and continue typing in Capitals. Not force him, he can anyway choose to write in lowercase from Keyboard

Answer (score 25):

It is not possible to force a capslock only via the XML. Also 3rd party libraries do not help. You could do a `toUpper()` on the text on the receiving side, but there's no way to prevent it on the keyboard side

You can use XML to set the keyboard to caps lock.

**Java**

You can set the `input_type` to  `TYPE_CLASS_TEXT| TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS`.  The `keyboard` should honor that.

**Kotlin**

`android:inputType="textCapCharacters"`

Comment: android:inputType="textCapCharacters"

Comment: I really don't know why this answer has so many upvotes. The solution doesn't avoid that the user disable capslock...

Comment: @kuzdu Since there's no API for keyboards to control that, especially not in 3rd party keyboards, there's no way to prevent that.  You could do a toUpper() on the text on the receiving side, but there's no way to prevent it on the keyboard side.

Answer (score 24):

You can used two way.

**First Way:**

Set `android:inputType="textCapSentences"` on your EditText.

**Second Way:**

When user enter the number you have to used text watcher and change small to capital letter.

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {            

    }
        @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {             
    }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable et) {
          String s=et.toString();
      if(!s.equals(s.toUpperCase()))
      {
         s=s.toUpperCase();
         edittext.setText(s);
         edittext.setSelection(edittext.length()); //fix reverse texting
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: your solution does not work because it sets the string on a reverse order.

Comment: which way you used first or second.

Comment: First one is not working at all. The second one makes the text upper case but we must programmetically set the cursor to the end of the sentence.

Comment: @Kalanamith ya then what's problem

Comment: Why do something programmatically when Android does it for you?

Comment: For first option textCapSentences capitalises sentences, you need textCapCharacters.

Comment: android:inputType="textCapCharacters"

Answer (score 16):

Even better... *one liner* in **Kotlin**...

```
// gets your previous attributes in XML, plus adds AllCaps filter    
<your_edit_text>.setFilters(<your_edit_text>.getFilters() + InputFilter.AllCaps())
```

Done!

Comment: You can write it using the property access syntax:

`<your_edit_text>.filters = <your_edit_text>.filters + InputFilter.AllCaps()`

Comment: Better yet:
`<your_edit_text>.filters += InputFilter.AllCaps()`

Answer (score 16):

Use input filter

```
editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enteredText);
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.AllCaps()});
```

Comment: it is causing issue when i press backspace/remove btn

Answer (score 14):

You can add the `android:textAllCaps="true"` property to your xml file in the EditText. This will enforce the softinput keyboard to appear in all caps mode. The value you enter will appear in Uppercase. However, this won't ensure that the user can only enter in `UpperCase` letters. If they want, they can still fall back to the lower case letters. If you want to ensure that the output of the `Edittext` is in All caps, then you have to manually convert the input String using `toUpperCase()` method of `String` class.

Comment: @GustavoAlves, Can you just tell me what happened when you tried this ? May be I can look into your issue. :)

Comment: Hi @Abhishek. Setting the property didn't change anything. The EditText still accept both uppercase and lowercase characters.

Comment: Yes if you want to restrict your EditText only to accept Uppercase characters then for you, android:inputType = "textCapCharacters" would be the right option. Give it a try and then let me know. ☺️

Comment: This caused and index out of bounds exception when every I typed.

Comment: can you give me the Java code snippet where you are tying to get the String from EditText  ??

Comment: `android:textAllCaps="true"` is only a property of TextView (https://stackoverflow.com/a/28803492/5268730). Use `android:inputType="textCapCharacters"` instead.

Answer (score 13):

You should put `android:inputType="textCapCharacters"` with Edittext in xml file.

Comment: AoyamaNanami wrote exactly the same answer. Please focus on more current questions, this one is from 2013. :)

Comment: Notice that user can shift and enter lower characters

Answer (score 12):

Rather than worry about dealing with the keyboard, why not just accept any input, lowercase or uppercase and convert the string to uppercase?

The following code should help:

```
EditText edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
String input;
....
input = edit.getText();
input = input.toUpperCase(); //converts the string to uppercase
```

This is user-friendly since it is unnecessary for the user to know that you need the string in uppercase.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Not really user friendly, because the UI doesn't indicate in any way, that the input is going to be handled as uppercase regardless of what they type on the keyboard.

Answer (score 10):

For me it worked by adding **android:textAllCaps="true"** and **android:inputType="textCapCharacters"**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/edit_text_height"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
                    />
```

Answer (score 9):

In **kotlin**, in .kt file make changes:

```
edit_text.filters = edit_text.filters + InputFilter.AllCaps()
```

Use synthetic property for direct access of widget with id.
And in XML, for your edit text add a couple of more flag as:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_text_qr_code"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ...other attributes...
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
    />
```

This will update the keyboard as upper case enabled.

Answer (score 9):

Try using any one of the below code may solve your issue.

programatically:

```
editText.filters = editText.filters + InputFilter.AllCaps()
```

XML :

```
android:inputType="textCapCharacters" with Edittext
```

Answer (score 8):

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {            

    }
        @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {             
    }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable et) {
          String s=et.toString();
      if(!s.equals(s.toUpperCase()))
      {
         s=s.toUpperCase();
         edittext.setText(s);
      }
      editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 7):

Simple kotlin realization

```
fun EditText.onlyUppercase() {
    inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT or InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS
    filters = arrayOf(InputFilter.AllCaps())
}
```

PS it seems that `filters` is always empty initially

Comment: This solution worked for me. XML Tag combination did not work for me. android:textAllCaps="true" and android:inputType="textCapCharacters"

Answer (score 7):

try this code it will make your input into upper case

```
edittext.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.AllCaps()});
```

Answer (score 6):

Just do this:

```
// ****** Every first letter capital in word *********
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textCapWords"
    />

//***** if all letters are capital ************

    android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on the accepted answer, this answer does the same, but in Kotlin. Just to ease copypasting :·)

```
private fun EditText.autocapitalize() {
    val allCapsFilter = InputFilter.AllCaps()
    setFilters(getFilters() + allCapsFilter)
}
```

Comment: `filters += InputFilter.AllCaps()` :D

Answer (score 3):

To get all capital, use the following in your XML:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
/>
```

Comment: have you tried this solution? this results in crash of application when user start to edit the content of editext

Answer (score 2):

To get **capitalized keyboard** when click **edittext** use this code in your xml,

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Input your country"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Visual Studio 2015/Xamarin to build my app for both Android 5.1 and Android 6.0 (same apk installed on both).

When I specified `android:inputType="textCapCharacters"` in my axml, the AllCaps keyboard appeared as expected on Android 6.0, but not Android 5.1.  I added `android:textAllCaps="true"` to my axml and still no AllCaps keyboard on Android 5.1.  I set a filter using `EditText.SetFilters(new IInputFilter[] { new InputFilterAllCaps() });` and while the soft keyboard shows lower case characters on Android 5.1, the input field is now AllCaps.

**EDIT:** The behavioral differences that I observed and assumed to be OS-related were actually because ***I had different versions of Google Keyboard on the test devices.***  Once I updated the devices to the latest Google Keyboard (released July 2016 as of this writing), the 'All Caps' behavior was consistent across OSes.  Now, all devices show lower-case characters on the keyboard, but the input is All Caps because of `SetFilters(new IInputFilter[] { new InputFilterAllCaps() });`

Comment: Hi Tony, it seems you have created 2 accounts; http://stackoverflow.com/users/6764633/tony-celia and http://stackoverflow.com/users/6771440/deeveedee. If you want to merge them, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts.

Comment: Thanks, Matt.  Chalk this one up to beginner learning/mistakes.  Didn't remember that I had created another account until you pointed it out.  fortunately, the account merge function was simple.  Great forum!

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin equivalent of ErlVolton's answer:

```
editText.SetFilters(editText.GetFilters().Append(new InputFilterAllCaps()).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

A Java 1-liner of the proposed solution could be:

```
editText.setFilters(Lists.asList(new InputFilter.AllCaps(), editText.getFilters())
    .toArray(new InputFilter[editText.getFilters().length + 1]));
```

Note it needs `com.google.common.collect.Lists`.

Answer (score 0):

#### 2021: Answer

This is the only latest answer if you want to get the `EditText` from `EditTextPreference`.

In order to change the `EditText` value or attributes, you need to set `setOnBindEditTextListener` callback as per the new AndroidX Kotlin.

```
findPreference<EditTextPreference>("key")?.setOnBindEditTextListener {
    it.filters = arrayOf<InputFilter>(InputFilter.AllCaps())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android:inputType="textCapCharacters|textAutoComplete"` in XML file

Answer (score 0):

On your XML side where you use an editText, this code below will force the input-user-text to make them all capital without Java code but XML:

```
    android:inputType="textAutoCorrect|none|numberSigned|textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions|number|datetime|textWebEmailAddress|textPersonName|textCapSentences|textPassword|textAutoComplete|textImeMultiLine|numberDecimal"
```

These can make the text input area all in capital by force with no doubt.
If you want to make not AllCaps, to turn off, don't write "**numberSigned**" in your XML code above.

Answer (score 0):

For Jetpack Compose TextField, it can be achieved in these ways

Setting a keyboard option

```
keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(capitalization = KeyboardCapitalization.Characters)
```

Or applying a visual transformation

```
class CapsCharacterVisualTransformation: VisualTransformation {
    override fun filter(text: AnnotatedString): TransformedText {
      return TransformedText(AnnotatedString(text.text.uppercase()), OffsetMapping.Identity)
    }
}

// usage
visualTransformation = CapsCharacterVisualTransformation()
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply, Add below code to your EditText of your xml file.

```
android:digits="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
```

And if you want to allow both uppercase text and digits then use below code.

```
android:digits="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890"
```

Comment: That works for sure, but it's not a very nice user experience. I just tried it out and as the keyboard doesn't autocapitalise (on N at least), lowercase typed characters are just ignored with no feedback to the user, making the UI seem broken.

Comment: completely agree with @MattMatt. If we do it the user will not be able to type small case letters. The user should be able to type whatever case he/she wants and the rest should auto uppercase the words