# How to capitalize every word in EditText?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

I want to capizalize every word typed in `EditText` inside `onTextChanged`. I've tried some solutions but none of them worked. Problem what I'm facing is if you change capitalize letter on keyboard and you will type `James JoNEs` it should repair that String to correct form after you type `E` character to `Jone`. This is not working with default `android:inputType="textCapWords"`. I've used some function what I've found but it is not working at all.

```
fun onFieldChanged(s: String, tv: TextWatcher, et: EditText) {
    et.removeTextChangedListener(tv)
    val changedString = capitalizeFirstLetterWord(s)
    with(et) {
        text.clear()
        append(changedString)
        setSelection(changedString.length)
    }
    et.addTextChangedListener(tv)
}

fun capitalizeFirstLetterWord(s: String): String{
    var finalStr = ""
    if(s != "") {
        val strArray = s.split("[\\s']")
        if (strArray.isNotEmpty()) {
            for(i in strArray.indices){
                finalStr+= capitalize(strArray[i])
            }
        }
    }
    return finalStr
}
```

Comment: Refer to this [answer link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15961813/in-android-edittext-how-to-force-writing-uppercase/15961909). You will find 2 methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to achieve that with something like this

`"yourString".split(" ").map { it.toLowerCase().capitalize() }.joinToString(" ")`

Comment: toLowerCase was the problem. Because capitalize will not change whole string to lower. It checks just first character